# Reason for not requiring numbers in a username

Tags: security, passwords

I've come across a system that requires you to include a number in your username. I feel this is pointless, as the username should be easy to remember, and not be subject to requirements that may be applied to passwords.

However I can't find a good write up of the reasons for this. Can anyone reference a good source for this, and/or explain it in better words than I can?

Edit: I'm getting answers explaining why they do this, which are certainly of value, but there must be a write up somewhere of how to make a secure login system, that advocates a simple, easy to remember username.

Comment: I suspect it's "security theatre".  I don't think it adds any real security, but it makes the system *seem* more secure to most users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having no clue about the specific system mentioned, if one can call support and say something like "My username is John and I forgot my password" - adding a number may add just a bit of security.

Also, if the system is not protected against brute-force attacks, one can try common usernames together with common passwords.

I agree with Xavjer: the reason for this is most likely not security-related.

I agree with you: If the requirement is security-related - the security scheme is probably wrong.

**Edit:**

Another idea - Maybe they want to force you to use a username which is different than the one you use on other sites. Since many users tend to select the same username and password for different sites, and in case the password is compromised on one of these sites - this may help (but again, just a bit).

Comment: The system is Barclaycard's online banking, and they're definitely justified in beefy security, but yeah, I don't think this is it. Quoting them "It's to enhance security." "We don't feel a secure password is enough to protect your info."

Comment: Of course I'm not under any impression that I'll be able to change their mind, so this is more a theoretical exercise (and desire for validation that I'm right :p)

Comment: It seems to me that obscurity of user names should not be part of a security model.  I shouldn't be able to break into your account by calling and saying "My username is john123 and I forgot my password".  Unless usernames are randomly generated and kept secret, restrictions don't seem useful.  (Not that I'm an expert.)

Comment: @Lior best justification for it yet I think (forcing different username) but that still means I have a username I can't remember well. Not their primary concern I guess. #Keith Agreed.

Comment: Hmm, not what I was going for but the closest to an explanation, so accepting this.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it could be because if you force a number in an username, you will most likely never receive a dublicate name problem. There wont be someone having for example the name 'peter' and then there is a 'peter95' and a 'peter112'. No one will have the original one.

This is just what I think is the most reasonable answer.

Comment: That's a justification *for* doing it. I'm looking for an explanation of why there's no point in doing so, from a security perspective.

Comment: If users select their own usernames, the system needs to check for duplicates anyway.  If I try to register with "peter112", the system needs to make exactly the same check as if I tried to register with "peter".

Comment: Meaning noone gets the username they want, rather than just the second person.